# Accordion widget closes automatically (is rebuilt) on state change - how to avoid this | Flutter

Tags: flutter, accordion, riverpod

I'm using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/accordion) beautiful Accordion package.

I have a few different situations where state changes in Accordion child widgets are causing entire Accordion widget rebuilds which in turn causes accordions to close on state change. My example below is highly simplified. The CustomRadioButton enforcedValue is the state change.

For example, a radio button is tapped, the state changes and the accordion closes. Upon reopening the accordion the state is updated.

Of course this is undesired, the entire accordion parent should not rebuild. I'm using Riverpod, the whole point of riverpod is to enact only rebuilds of child widgets that require it and not rebuild larger parents.

I have tried messing around with keys but I don't have any conclusive good changes to report along this line.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there something I can change while maintaining widget reusability as I currently have?

```
class Page extends ConsumerWidget {
  const Page({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    // Exemplary boolean visibility values (not important for this, just showing for example)
    bool one = true;
    bool two = true;
    bool three = true;

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          pulldownExample(context, ref, null),
          Visibility(visible: one, child: pulldownExample(context, ref, 0)),
          Visibility(visible: two, child: pulldownExample(context, ref, 1)),
          Visibility(visible: three, child: pulldownExample(context, ref, 2)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  // FP magnitude notification pulldown
  Widget pulldownExample(
    BuildContext context,
    WidgetRef ref,
    int? index,
  ) {
    return Accordion(
      scaleWhenAnimating: false,
      openAndCloseAnimation: true,
      flipRightIconIfOpen: true,
      disableScrolling: true,
      children: [
        AccordionSection(
          header: Text('DYNAMIC HEADER TEXT'),
          content: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  CustomRadioButton(
                    enforcedValue: ref.watch(exampleState).valueOne, // Trouble here when this state changes
                    onTap: (_) => onTapLogic(),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 8),
                  Text('ONE'),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  CustomRadioButton(
                    enforcedValue: ref.watch(exampleState).valueTwo, // Trouble here when this state changes
                    onTap: (_) => onTapLogic(),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 8),
                  Text('TWO'),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  CustomRadioButton(
                    enforcedValue: ref.watch(exampleState).valueThree, // Trouble here when this state changes
                    onTap: (_) => onTapLogic(),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 8),
                  Text('THREE'),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, your `pulldownExample` method needs to be converted into a separate `ConsumerWidget` widget with the required fields. This will optimize rebuilds.

Second, you can use the `Consumer` widget inside the `build` method to rebuild only those parts of the tree that need to be rebuilt. Also consider using `select` for the `exampleState` provider.

Links:

- [The problem with splitting widgets into methods](https://iiro.dev/splitting-widgets-to-methods-performance-antipattern/)

Comment: Sure I could probably put the pullDownExample into it's own reusable widget. I don't think that will fix my functionality issue though. Second, my Custom radio buttons are already reusable widgets and enforcedValue correctly rebuilds the widgets in other areas of the app. My problem is weird functionality within the accordion and I don't think that Consumer would fix it. Do you have any other ideas? Also a code example would help if you're making any suggestions.

Comment: Your `pullDownExample` method rebuilds the widgets over and over again with ANY changes -- this is not an optimization. You could use a standalone widget, or use the `Consumer` + `select` method on the `ref.watch(exampleState)` provider. I've also pinned a link why it's preferable to use a separate widget instead of methods.

Comment: Obviously, you want only the button that tracks that value to be rebuilt when `valueOne` changes. Now the entire widget tree and all 3 available buttons are being rebuilt.

Comment: Your answer was very close but I tried all various angles including your suggestions and they didn't work. What ended up working was creating a seprate ConsumerWidget for the radio button sections ONLY. The problem was passing the WidgetRef via the accordion caused rebuilds of the parent which caused the accordion to reset in closed position. This was a valuable lesson in state management :)

Comment: >a seprate ConsumerWidget for the radio button sections ONLY< that's what I meant, since it's the buttons that need to be rebuilt. I'm glad it worked out for you! :)